# What could cause Angular HTTP request to stall until browser is resized?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I'm maintaining an internal Angular web app while the employee responsible for it is away. My background is more PHP/backend. Immediately after he departed, our users started complaining that nothing in our web app "saves". Upon closer inspection (in the Chrome Developer Tools network tab) I see our web app making an HTTP `OPTIONS` preflight request that stalls indefinitely.

Here's where it gets weird: I can see the `OPTIONS` request in our Apache access logs show up immediately when the save button is clicked. I confirmed that our backend returns a 204 response code with no body in less than a second (by copying the `OPTIONS` request as cURL and making the request from the command line). In our dev environment everything is plain-old-HTTP, so there are no certs or proxies involved.

Now here's the part that will really bake your noodle. Chrome remains in that catatonic state until I do one of two things:

1. Resize the window
2. Switch tabs

When I do either of the above, Chrome seems to "wake up" from its coma, immediately processes the `OPTIONS` response (that it got minutes before), and immediately follows it up with the `PUT` to update the resource. Crazy right? Hard to tell if this is a bug in Chrome, or if somewhere in the guts of our app (or Angular) something is causing JavaScript to wait for some external event (triggered by the window resize) before processing the `OPTIONS` response.

As far as I know I've got the latest version of Chrome (43.0.2357.81 (64-bit)) running on Mac OS X Yosemite. Our web app is using AngularJS v1.2.28, but I've also confirmed the bug with v1.3.15. Unfortunately my Angular-foo is weak, so I haven't yet been able to create a small Angular testcase. I'm just hoping that this odd scenario rings a bell for someone out there who can point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Does this only happen in chrome latest? not firefox?

Comment: Correct, it only happens in Chrome, not in Firefox.

Comment: The problem persists in Chrome version 43.0.2357.124 (64-bit)